# JSON for family tree Neo4J and React Tree Graph

Tags: reactjs, spring, neo4j

I am using Neo4J to manage the family tree, I want to get 3 generations of a person and display it in the React Tree Graph library. The JSON structure I need will look like this:

```
{
  "name": "Alex Statham",
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Jason Statham",
      "people": [
        {
          "name": "Lyna Statham"
        },
        {
          "name": "John Statham"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Will Statham",
      "people": [
        {
          "name": "Michael Statham"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my family tree in Neo4J:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk5LY.png

This is my query to create that family tree:

```
create (bn1:Person{maBN:1,name:"Anna William",address:"American"})
create (bn2:Person{maBN:2,name:"Jason Statham",address:"American"})
create (bn3:Person{maBN:3,name:"Lyna Statham",address:"American"})
create (bn4:Person{maBN:4,name:"John Statham",address:"American"})
create (bn5:Person{maBN:5,name:"Alex Statham",address:"American"})
create (bn6:Person{maBN:6,name:"Will Statham",address:"American"})
create (bn7:Person{maBN:7,name:"Michael Statham",address:"American"})

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person),(c:Person),(d:Person)
WHERE a.name contains 'Jason' AND b.name contains 'Anna' and c.name contains 'John' and d.name contains 'Lyna'
CREATE (b)-[:PARENT_OF {type: 'natural'}]->(c)
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF {type: 'natural'}]->(c)
CREATE (b)-[:PARENT_OF {type: 'natural'}]->(d)
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF {type: 'natural'}]->(d)
RETURN a, b, c ,d

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name contains 'Jason' AND b.name contains 'Anna'
CREATE (a)-[:SPOUSE_OF {type:'marriage'}]->(b)
CREATE (b)-[:SPOUSE_OF {type:'marriage'}]->(a)
RETURN a, b

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name contains 'Alex' AND b.name contains 'Jason' 
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF {type:'natural'}]->(b)
RETURN a, b

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name contains 'Alex' AND b.name = 'Will Statham' 
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF {type:'adopted child'}]->(b)
RETURN a, b

MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name='Will Statham' AND b.name contains 'Michael' 
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF {type:'step'}]->(b)
RETURN a, b
```

I tried several of query and procedure like these:

```
//Test 1 (It lacks a brother'child and of course it not return a JSON)
Match (otherssubchild)-[a:PARENT_OF]-(othersubchild)-[:PARENT_OF]-(otherchild)-[:PARENT_OF]-(parent)-[:PARENT_OF]-(b:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]-(children)-[:PARENT_OF]-(subchild)
where b.name contains 'Jason' 
return parent,b,children,subchild,otherchild,othersubchild,otherssubchild

//Test 2 (It return a JSON but it not actually right and It wrong because start Node p1, p1 will always display like the oldest person)
MATCH (p1:Person {maBN:2})
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(p1, {
    sequence: '>Person,PARENT_OF,>Person,PARENT_OF,>Person',
    maxLevel: 3
}) YIELD path
With collect(path) as R
Call apoc.convert.toTree(R) yield value
return value

//Test 3 (It looks good but is only true in the case of not indicating whose generation and in most cases is wrong.)
Match (a:Person)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(b:Person)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(c:Person) 
WITH a,b,{name:c.name} as gen1 
WITH a,{name:b.name, people:collect(gen1)} as gen2 
WITH a,{name:a.name, people:collect(gen2)} as tree 
return tree
```

But none of them is true. What do I have to do to get the JSON perfect for the library? Please someone help me!

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider following the GEDCOM or GEDCOMx standard. This would include people (INDV), unions (FAMS), and place (PLAC) nodes at a minimum. You can see how I rendered this in Neo4j at [this blog post.](http://stumpf.org/genealogy-blog/graph-databases-in-genealogy). I do the ETL from GEDCOM or (queries of my SQL Server) database to Neo4j using CSV files and the LOAD CSV method for Neo4j. But you could also do the ETL via JSON. My main point is to consider your Neo4j schema; right now it looks too limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query may work for your specific case. However, the blog post mentioned by @david-a-stumpf has a bunch of great content to consider.

```
MATCH path = (:Person {name: "Alex Statham"})-[:PARENT_OF*1..3]->(:Person)
With collect(path) as R
Call apoc.convert.toTree(R) yield value
return value
```